# Creating a managed package from two managed Package

Tags: package

I have two different managed packages installed in my Dev org and now i have create an connector unmanaged package in it.Now i need to create managed package of all three .Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use files from other's managed packages in new one.

It is clearly understandable, because you may download someone else's managed package, wrap it and make money with not your own work.

However, if you have code from the packages, you can download all files to sandbox as native classes, not as manages packages, and create the package that will obtain all instances.